# Setting Dockerfile Variables Dynamically Using Docker Compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, environment-variables, containers

I'm working on a Docker project where I want to set all the parameters in my Dockerfile dynamically, without passing parameters during the build process. Instead, I'd like to specify all the required variables in my Docker Compose file. Specifically, I want to set the base image for my Docker image using a variable within the Docker Compose file, something like:

Dockerfile:

```
# Set base image
FROM ${BASE_IMAGE}
```

Here's my Docker Compose file:

```yaml
version: "3.8"

services:
  my-service:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
        BASE_IMAGE: python:3.6.6-alpine3.7
```

However, it doesn't seem to work as expected. The `BASE_IMAGE` variable set in the Docker Compose file does not affect the `FROM` statement in the Dockerfile during runtime.

Is there a way to achieve this dynamic configuration using Docker Compose? How can I define and use variables within my Docker Compose file to set values in the Dockerfile without having to pass parameters during the build process?

Comment: Did you use `ARG BASE_IMAGE`? From https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/ it needs to be before the `FROM` step to be available

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-arg-and-from-interact,

> FROM instructions support variables that are declared by any ARG instructions that occur before the first FROM.

You need to set a default for BASE_IMAGE first:

```
ARG BASE_IMAGE=python:3.6.6-alpine3.7

FROM ${BASE_IMAGE}
```

And you can dynamically change it using your compose file etc.

Comment: Does it have to be on a Dockerfile can it be declared in a` .env` file or something?

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't look so. This is Dockerfile syntax and it won't work other than the way stated in the docs. Are you unable to modify the Dockerfile?

The default ARG doesn't really matter as long as you are overriding with the compose file.

Comment: Ok, I see thank you. Then there is no point in passing arguments from the docker compose filer then, right?

Comment: Only if you still need to change it externally (e.g. if you use multiple compose files). If you don't, then the `ARG` in the Dockerfile is sufficient.